# Unfamiliar variable assignment with parenthesis and commas

Tags: javascript

Why does assigning values with parenthesis like this only evaluate to the last value

```
 var a = (1, 2, 5 - 1); //4
```

It also seems to require the parenthesis

```
var a = 1, 5 - 1; //SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Comment: When you add parentheses, then the expression to the right of the `=` symbol is a comma operator sequence. A list of expressions separated by commas has as its value the value of the last expression in the list.

Comment: @Pointy I can't give you any magical unicorn points if you don't use the answer box!

Comment: @Pointy Why to use then if it only takes last one?

Comment: @Scimonster sorry I was looking for a duplicate; seems like just a few days ago I stumbled across a question almost identical to this one ... I can't find it however.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `,` symbol has several similar but distinctly different roles in JavaScript syntax.  In a `var` declaration, the comma separates variable declaration clauses. In an expression, however, the comma "operator" provides a way to stuff several expressions together in a form that is syntactically equivalent to a single expression. That's somewhat useful in certain rare cases.

Thus, the parentheses make a difference here because without them, the parser expects each comma-separated clause to be a variable declaration and (optional) initialization. With the parentheses, the right-hand side of the initialization is a single expression, syntactically, even though it's three separate unrelated expressions connected by the comma operator.

The comma operator in expressions is arguably useful when there's a situation that involves syntax that allows for a single expression, but you really want to use more than one. The best example is the third clause in a `for` loop header.  If you need to increment two separate variables, then it (may) be clearer to do that in the loop header; however, there's only provision for one expression. Thus the comma operator lets you cheat:

```
for (var a = 0, b = 1; a < limit; a++, b = something(b)) {
  // ...
}
```

Note that the comma in the *first* clause of the `for` header is *not* the comma operator; it's the comma that separates variable declaration clauses. (I guess some people might still use the term "comma operator" for that, but my point is that it's not separating a list of *expressions*.)

Comment: Can you provide any examples of some of the "rare cases"? Thanks

Comment: @thomas `for` loops are one example. Check out the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator '**,**' evaluates each of its operands ( from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.You can have multiple expressions evaluated with the final value been the value of the rightmost expression.

```
let x = 9;
x = (x++, x*2, x*3)

// output: x = 30
```

This use of compound expressions and assignment is helpful in conditional operators, in for loops.

**Note:**
Without the parentheses,

```
let x = 9;
x = x++, x*2, x*3

// output: x = 27
```

[From the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

```
var a, b, c;
a = b = 3, c = 4; // Returns 4 in console

console.log(a); // 3 (left-most)

var x, y, z;
x = (y = 5, z = 6); // Returns 6 in console

console.log(x); // 6 (right-most)
```

[See also MDN operator precedence docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)