# Explain the value of a JavaScript variable when the value has multiple data types and it is inside a parenthesis citation

Tags: javascript

This was a question I was asked and was completely stumped.

```
var a = (1, 2, 3);
console.log(a);
```

I found out that a = 3 and was wondering why the value is equaled to the last number in the parenthesis. It works the same if there were strings. This confused me since I never seen the value of a variable cited in parenthesis, when would someone use this?

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217112/unfamiliar-variable-assignment-with-parenthesis-and-commas

Comment: Or even this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m

Comment: please welcome the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)!

Comment: Why do you think the value has multiple data types? They're all numbers.