# what does var x = (y, z) do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I've seen in JavaScript code like:

```
var x = (1, 2);
```

which would then evaluate x to 2. Also

```
var x = (false, 2);
```

also evaluates x to 2, or any other value (so it **doesn't** appear to be identical to var `x = false || 2`).

It would appear so far that the value of x in this case is always equal to the second comma-separated value, so then what's the point exactly? **What does the expression `var x = (y, z);` do?**

Comment: As for "What's the point?": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/when-is-the-comma-operator-useful

Comment: And here's a more detailed description: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217112/unfamiliar-variable-assignment-with-parenthesis-and-commas